# How to Default export react withRouter while using material UI makeStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am using Material UI makeStyles with class components and adding use style as props while default exporting it in an arrow function.

```
export default () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <LoginClass classes={classes} />
  )
}
```

In react documentation it states that you need to use hooks while using makestyles which currently until now I have been doing correctly.

The issue I am facing now is I want to use react withRouter to use:

> this.props.history.push

which I dont have access to in my class.

Below is my code that works perfectly but I cant direct users to other pages.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: '#009688',
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    backgroundColor: '#33ab9f',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#009688',
    },
  },
}));
```

```
class LoginClass extends React.Component {
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
        this.props.history.push('/home') //dont have access to history unless I use withRouter
                      }
render() {
    const classes = this.props.classes;
    const { input } = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <MenuBarClass classes={classes} isLogin={this.state.isLogin} />
      </React.Fragment>
   )
  }
}
```

After alot of research I have found a way to direct users to other pages by using:

```
export default withRouter(withStyles(useStyles)(LoginClass))
```

but using the above export distorts my whole page design.

any solution with using classes and makeStyles would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
so I can direct the users to other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: '#009688',
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    backgroundColor: '#33ab9f',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#009688',
    },
  },
});      

...

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(LoginClass))
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxAlex . It fixed the issue